# CTRL+ALT+L behavior in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android-studio

I need to add indentations to a new java file I just added to my Android project. Currently everything is hard against the left margin.  All over Stack Overflow there is advice saying that this can be done in Android Studio with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

But when I select a block of text in my code and do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> I get a popup dialog titled Reformat File: *(my file name)*, with radio buttons for Scope and Optional.  Under Scope I have "Selected text", and under Optional I have nothing.  When I click Run the dialog goes away but nothing changes.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you actually just had the caps lock key on. But interestingly to note is that the Reformat File dialog really does not seem to work when the Selected Text option is checked. It works with a regular shortcut though.

Comment: _But interestingly to note is that the Reformat File dialog really does not seem to work when the Selected Text option is checked._ Then how do I just reformat a block of selected text in Android Studio?

Comment: For me, CTRL+ALT+l (lowercase L) works just fine when the text is selected. And disregard my above statement about the Reformat Dialog not working, it does work in Android Studio, but not in CLion.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you are on windows. On Mac the equivalent sequence is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

In order to see the popup that you are seeing I need to add <kbd>shift</kbd> in the sequence. Which now becomes <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Try on your side to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Make sure you don't have a sticky <kbd>shift</kbd> key/cap lock ?

To check the sequence setup in your config, go to `preferences` -> `Keymap` and search for `auto-indent lines`

Comment: As the title suggests, I'm using a capital "L", that is I'm holding down the CTRL key and the Alt key and pressing the shift and "L" keys at the same time.  .   But I'm unclear from your answer if that's what you mean by "ctrl + Alt + shift + L"  Because shift+capital L produces a lowercase "L".

Comment: Oh ok. You have to do lowercase L to auto indent your code. That means, don't press shift. If a letter in a sequence is required to be uppercase, it would specify holding shift key as well.

Comment: All letters in a sequence are usually written in capital, as it is the way the appear on your keyboard.

Comment: The case of the L doesn't make any difference  ctrl alt "L" and ctrl alt "l" produce the same result, i.e., no indentation.

Comment: Make sure you select the text you want to indent first.